# How to set an annotation to a variable

Tags: annotations, data-annotations, nunjucks

How do I set an annotation to a variable.

```
{{ x }}
{%set x = {{issue.fields.reporter.name}} %}
{{ x }}
```

I expect the name of the reporter to be copied to x, and that doesn't happen.

Appreciate you help!

Comment: `{% set x = issue.fields.reporter.name %}` ?